# PostgreSQL regexp_replace with matched expression

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am using PostgreSQL `regexp_replace` function to escape square brackets, parentheses and backslash in a string so that I could use that string as a regex pattern itself (there are other manipulations done on this string as well before using it, but they are outside the scope of this question.  The idea is to replace:

`[` with `\[`
`]` with `\]`
`(` with `\(`
`)` with `\)`
`\` with `\\`

[Postgres documentation page on regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) states the following:

> The replacement string can contain \n, where n is 1 through 9, to
>   indicate that the source substring matching the n'th parenthesized
>   subexpression of the pattern should be inserted, and it can contain \&
>   to indicate that the substring matching the entire pattern should be
>   inserted. Write \ if you need to put a literal backslash in the
>   replacement text.

However `regexp_replace('abc [def]', '([\[\]\(\)\\])', E'\\\1', 'g');` produces `abc \ def\`.

Further down on that same page, an example is given, which uses `\\1` notation - so I tried that.

Yet, `regexp_replace('abc [def]', '([\[\]\(\)\\])', E'\\\\1', 'g');` produces `abc \1def\1`.

I would guess this is expected, but `regexp_replace('abc [def]', '([\[\]\(\)\\])', E'.\\1', 'g');` produces `abc .[def.]`.  That is, escaping works with characters other than the standard backslash.

At this point I don't know how to proceed.  What can I do to actually give me the replacement I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, found the answer.  Apparently, I need to double-escape the backslash in the replacement.  Also, I need to `E`-prefix and double-escape backslashes in the search pattern on older versions of postgres (8.3 in my case).  The final code looks like this:

```
regexp_replace('abc [def]', E'([\\[\\]\\(\\)\\\\\?\\|_%])', E'\\\\\\1', 'g')
```

Yes, it looks horrible, but it works :)

Comment: If you have `standard_conforming_strings` on (as is the default in recent versions) and you *don't* use the `E` prefix you eliminate a lot of backslashes, and it looks less horrible: `regexp_replace('abc [def]', '([\[\]\(\)\\?\|_%])', '\\\1', 'g')`.

Comment: @kgrittn Yes, I appreciate it.  Unfortunately, our servers are 8.3 and these were required.  Without `E`, it would complain that `E` is required if escapes are used and with `E` it required the double-escaping.

Comment: Fair enough. For the record, you can turn on `standard_conforming_strings` in any version from 8.2 on, but it isn't the default until 9.0. The `E` prefix, while it looks uglier, has the advantage of working regardless of this setting.

Answer (score 2):

it's simpliest way

```
select regexp_replace('abc [def]', '([\[\]\(\)\\])', '\\\1', 'g')
```