# PostgreSQL regexp_replace to add new lines or break tags to field

Tags: markdown, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to update a field in a database table.  The field contains this text:

```
Course Focus: This course will focus on...
```

I want to add some Markdown syntax to this field so the "Course Focus" part is a header and the rest appears under it with a blank line between them.  There are many records and I thought I could use regexp_replace to update all the records at once.  I want:

```
## Course Focus

This course will focus on...
```

I've tried this:

```
update courses 
   set course_focus = regexp_replace(course_focus, 'Course Focus:', '## Course Focus ##\n\r\n\r', 'g');
```

When this display in a web-page it is all bolded and no line breaks:

```
**Course Focus \n\r\n\r This course will focus on...**  (all bold)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The asterisks are from me trying to bold the display in my post.  They are not a part of the output I see in postgres or html.

Comment: can you provide the HTML output rather than just the text displayed in the browser? Use "view source" if you have to and edit your question to show the actual HTML code. That will be much more helpful in understanding what your problem is. For that matter, it may be even more helpful to see the plain (Markdown) text returned by postgres when you retrieve the field.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) states:

> Write `\\` if you need to put a literal backslash in the replacement text.

In this case you do want a literal backslash. Remember that your SQL statement will be interpreted and `\n` will be seen as a newline in the SQL statement rather than a newline in the value. However, you want to pass the newline on to the field as part of the value, so you need an extra backslash: `\\n`. Then the SQL statement parser will remove one backslash and pass `\n` on to the field for storage. You can find similar issues in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12088271/866026). Alternatively, as pointed out in that question/answer, you can use the `E` prefix to avoid the the need for double escaping.

As an aside, you do not need the carriage return: `\r`. Markdown parsers normalize line endings to `\n` as one of their first steps. The carriage return offers no value. Of course, if you really want it, you can leave it in, but I've removed it from my example for clarity.

Also, its not completely clear from your description, but if "`Course Focus:`" only occurs once per field, then the `g` flag can be removed, which will speed up the procedure. With the `g` flag, the regex will need to continue searching the rest of the text field for additional matches when it could have stopped after the first match. So you may want to remove the `g` flag.

The final statement should look like this:

```
update courses 
   set course_focus = regexp_replace(course_focus, 'Course Focus:', '## Course Focus ##\\n\\n');
```

Or like this, if you use the E prefix:

```
update courses 
   set course_focus = regexp_replace(course_focus, 'Course Focus:', E'## Course Focus ##\n\n');
```

Comment: update courses set course_focus = regexp_replace(course_focus, 'Course Focus:', '## Course Focus ## \\n\\n');

Comment: ## Course Focus ## \n\n This course will focus on...   The Browser is not interpolating the newlines into blank lines on the page.  View source shows the same:  <p>## Course Focus ## \n\n     This course will focus on...